# Local redirect sends a ghost GET request for some reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a site with the following behavior :

- If the user attempts to get to the /home page without being authenticated, he gets redirected to the /login page.
- Once he logs in through the /login page, he receive a session cookie and gets redirected to the /home page
- If the user gets back to the /login page but has a valid session cookie, he gets automatically redirected to the /home page

I'm using node.js with express.
Here is the current code I use :
Server-side :

```js
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {   
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/login.html")
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    //try to authenticate the user
    //if invalid user_id or password
    res.status(401).end();
    //else creating a cookie and registering the session
    res.cookie("session_token", sessionToken, { sameSite: 'Strict', expires: expiresAt })
    res.cookie("session_id", id, { sameSite: 'Strict', expires: expiresAt })
    res.status(200).send()
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    //if the user can't be authenticated 
    if (!function_to_authenticate_the_user(req)) return res.redirect(308,'/login')
    //else
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + "/html/home.html")
});

app.get('/isSessionValid', loginRL, (req, res) => {
    if (function_to_authenticate_the_user(req)) return res.status(200).send();
    else return res.status(401).send()  
});
```

User-side (function is triggered by an onclick property on a button) :

```js
function login(id, mdp) {
    fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'id': id,
            'password': password
        })
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.status === 401) {
            // display error message
        } else if (res.status === 200) {
            location.replace('/home')
        }
    })
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (!document.cookie) return
    const cookies = Object.fromEntries(document.cookie.split('; ').map(c => c.split('=')));
    if (!cookies.session_token || !cookies.session_id) return
    fetch('/isSessionValid', {
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) location.replace('/home')
    })
});
```

The issue :

For some reason I don't understand, once the user sends a POST request to /login and get a 200 response with a cookie, it sends a GET request to the /home page (which is what it should do) BUT ALSO another GET request to the /login page (and I don't understand why)

It sends both requests at the same time. And for some reason the (second) /login request gets prioritized and the browser automatically interprets the GET /home as a 308 status (the server NEVER receive any request to /home)

And since the user now has a valid session cookie, the browser tries again to redirect to /home but also automatically sends another GET request to /login and over and over again.

I tried to debug both server-side and user-side.
For some reason, the server seems to never get any GET request from /home
I tried to remove the window load event listener but it stills sends another get request to /login and never redirects successfully to /home (it just stops the never ending loop of requests)

When I manually sets the url to /home from a current /login page, the same behavior happens (a ghost request to /login and doesn't load /home)
I tried to change the server code to :

```js
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    console.log('received a request')
    if (!function_to_authenticate_the_user(req)) {
        console.log('trying to redirect')
        return res.redirect(301,'/login') 
    }
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + "/html/home.html")
});
```

but the browsers keeps displaying the following requests in the console :

```
GET http://localhost:8000/home [HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect 0ms]
GET http://localhost:8000/login [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
```

and the server never logs anything.

I tried to remove the location.replace('/home') in the user-side code but it didn't solve the issue.

What am I missing ?

Comment: It looks like you are handling every GET request to /home by redirecting it to /login inside your handler function.

Comment: There was a if/else instruction I changed while writing it here, I'll change it on the post (but it is on my server's code)

Comment: Definitely shouldn't use any kind of permanent redirect is this situation. Permanent redirects are cached and it's up to the browser to re-validate them which can be never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is caching your 308 redirect.
For testing purposes you can clear your cache and disable caching in your browser (in Chrome: inspect -> network tab -> check disable cache)

Since Express is using HTTP [code 302 for redirects](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) by default, you could change `res.redirect(308,'/login')` to `res.redirect('/login')`